# Pass Wrong Information in stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I wrote some stored procedure to transfer 2 tables data to a new, merged table.

- Table 1 -> OldUsers table
- Table 2 -> Hunters Table
- Table 3 ->  Users table

Table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [uid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [username] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [password] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [state] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [license] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lansno] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [curcuit_no] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [communism] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Olduid] [int] NULL,
    [Is_hunter] [bit] NULL,
    [free_text] [text] NULL,
    [country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [curcuit] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [license_territory] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [forest] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [association] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [hunt_ar] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [area] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [contract] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [radio_frequency] [varchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_timeuser] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([uid] ASC)
)
```

I wrote some stored procedure to import data. BUT when I normally execute then pass ALL NULLS (whole table filled with NULLS). After that I remove

```
Where @uid = @index;
```

and then execute. Then I saw one id repeated everywhere.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserTransfer]
AS
    declare @OldUser_tbl_count int;
    declare @Hunters_tbl_count int;

    declare @index int;
    set @index = 1;

    declare @uid int;
    declare @usr varchar(50);
    declare @psw varchar(50);
    declare @stat int;
    declare @name varchar(50);
    declare @license varchar(50);
    declare @lansno varchar(50);
    declare @curcuit varchar(50);
    declare @commu varchar(100);
    declare @sid int;
    --declare @text text;
    declare @country varchar(50);
    declare @curc varchar(50);
    declare @terri varchar(50);
    declare @forest varchar(50);
    declare @assoc varchar(50);
    declare @hunt varchar(50);
    declare @area varchar(50); 
    declare @contract varchar(50);
    declare @radio varchar(50);
    declare @town varchar(100);
    declare @lans varchar(50);

    --SET @OldUser_tbl_count = (SELECT COUNT (*) from OldUsers)
    SELECT @OldUser_tbl_count = COUNT (*) from OldUsers;
    SELECT @Hunters_tbl_count = COUNT (*) from Hunters;

-- entering from OldUsers to Users tbl
while(@index <= @OldUser_tbl_count)
BEGIN
    Select @uid=OldUsers.uid , @usr=OldUsers.username , @psw=OldUsers.password , @stat=OldUsers.state,
@name = dbo.OldUsers.name, @license=OldUsers.license,@curcuit= OldUsers.curcuit_no,@commu= OldUsers.communism,@lans=OldUsers.lansno
FROM OldUsers 
Where @uid=@index;

INSERT INTO Users
Values (@usr,@psw,@stat,@name,@license,@lans,@curcuit,@commu,@uid,0,'','','','','','','','','','');

SET @index = @index+1;
END

-- entering from Hunters to Users tbl
While (@index <= @Hunters_tbl_count)
BEGIN
SELECT @uid=Hunters.id,@license=Hunters.licence,@name=Hunters.hunter,@country=Hunters.country,@curc=Hunters.circuit,
@terri=Hunters.licence_territory,@forest=Hunters.forest,@assoc=Hunters.association,@hunt=Hunters.hunt_ar,@area=Hunters.area,
@contract=Hunters.contract,@radio=Hunters.radio_frequency,@town=Hunters.town

From Hunters
Where @uid = @index;

INSERT INTO Users
VALUES      ('','','',@name,@license,'','',@town,@uid,1,'',@country,@curc,@terri,@forest,@assoc,@hunt,@area,@contract,@radio);

SET @index=@index+1;
END

-exec UserTransfer
```

Comment: You probably ment `Where uid=@index;` instead of `Where @uid=@index;`

Comment: You could [insert directly from one table to another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) using insert into ... select.

Comment: I just tried out it.Where uid=@index;.But Same NULL Passed.

Comment: But, you said ... you intentionally passing null values right?

Comment: Here i have merged 2 tables.& also Old tables ID cvaluesd should comes to new tables Oldid coloumn.thats why i wrote this stored procedure

Comment: @Rahul - i passed some NULL values intentioanlly.becase some coloumns in Only 1 table,then when i passed with other coloumn i put NULL values there..but now the problem is Filled NULL everywhere..

Comment: RESULT SHOWN HERE >> [link](http://images.cjb.net/5fb84.png)

Comment: If you have problem with hunters only, it is because you did not reset @index to 1.

Comment: Initially i set  set @index=1; ??

Comment: Yes, but not before second loop - `@index` will have value of `@OldUser_tbl_count + 1` - perhaps this is intentional? But, as change in where did not work, could you confirm that IDs and UIDs are sequential and start from 1?

Comment: There is an error on the script to create the USERS table, lack of parenthesis at the end. Also you should post HUNTERS table creation script and other script to fill them with test data.

Comment: OldUser uid starting with 92. Hunters starting with 1.Both those ID's should go to Oldid coloumn in Users table.In Users table uid is autoincrement.

Comment: @Yaroslav - here i pass Empty strings there.because that data not in that table but that data comes from another table...

Comment: There you go - you select users with id 1 to 91 from oldusers, and there are not such records.

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović - so how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try this two inserts?

```
INSERT INTO Users
Select username, [password], [state], name, license, lansno, curcuit_no, communism, [Uid], 0 ,'','','','','','','','','',''
FROM OldUsers 

INSERT INTO Users
SELECT '', '', '', Hunter, licence, '', '', town, ID, 1, '', country, circuit, licence_territory, forest, association, hunt_ar, area, [contract], radio_frequency
From Hunters
```

Instead of selecting and inserting data record by record you can do it at once. Please check [this link to Sql Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: With or without Where clause ?

Comment: @chathuraRanasinghe Exactly as written here. No where, no `@`

Comment: @chathuraRanasinghe What I ment was not to put this two inserts in your procedure, but rather run them directly.

Comment: I use your code with my while loop.then records recorded infinitely, Without while loop then i saw 547 Rows affected message but theres no record in my Users table ?

Comment: No while loop, no your procedure, execute *exactly as written*

Comment: - Wow Simply did it.thanks lot.Can you please tell me How to get INSERT INTO SELECT form another Database..Let's say OldUser table in another database like People ?

Comment: @chathuraRanasinghe If the database is attached to same server, prepend name of the database and schema to table name, for instance `People.dbo.OldUsers`. If not, you will have to use [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but this is a bit difficult to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using WHILE, it hurts performance a lot, it's like using a CURSOR. In this case I would recommend using INSERT INTO...SELECT, [check this link from Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/10/sql-server-use-insert-into-select-instead-of-cursor/) for a detailed explanation on how to substitute a cursor with a INSERT INTO...SELECT clause.

Check [Microsoft MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174633%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more info

Comment: Can i know what is the problem to pass nulls here ?

Comment: Just created all the needed tables and procedure, populated with fake data OldUsers and Hunters tables and then executed the stored proc. Works fine for me. Needed to change the where on both inserts to show uid=@index. Also you misspeleed "circuit" and "licence_territory" on the creation script.

Comment: @Yaroslav Id's are wrong, that's why he is getting nulls - select, even repaired one, does not get any record.

Comment: ....edited... only Users table are inserted as index keeps last value when exiting from the first while. Need to add a SET @index=1 between each while, so the second one starts from first. As @Nikola Markovinović, pointed out, if identity columns does not couple then NULL inserts will be done. For me it worked as I populated the data with correct values.

Answer (score 0):

change `Where @uid=@index;` to `OldUsers.uid` on old users

and

`Where @uid = @index;`  to  `Hunters.id` on hunters

Comment: Result is same... NULL Passed

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a different approach?

try to tun this:

```
INSERT INTO Users 
select username, password,state, name, license, lansno, curcuit_no, communism, uid,0,'','','','','','','','','',''
from OldUsers
```

you may have to add columns' names after the insert into